# ListView Padding cannot be modified

Tags: flutter

Working on [such a line](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/460dd20802b8ed92246b75d334cf0ad6520999b5/lib/pages/home.dart#L169) to add padding before `ListView` i.e. on top. Whatever I do, the `ListView` doesn't move lower to have more distance on top. I have tried many variations of:

```dart
      return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          // ...
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 800), // Tried many variations here, but no change is observed in result
          children: [
            // ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a mistake. I'm on mobile, so I'm *not* on desktop. But there is an `if` condition [here](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/460dd20802b8ed92246b75d334cf0ad6520999b5/lib/pages/home.dart#L137) right before the `ListView`:

```dart
if (isDesktop) {
  // ...
  return Scaffold(
 // ...
```

To change the padding on mobile, I should be concerned with  `} else {` statement [here](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/460dd20802b8ed92246b75d334cf0ad6520999b5/lib/pages/home.dart#L240) which eventually returns [this `Stack`](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/460dd20802b8ed92246b75d334cf0ad6520999b5/lib/pages/home.dart#L365). I just needed to change this [`SizedBox(height ...`](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/460dd20802b8ed92246b75d334cf0ad6520999b5/lib/pages/home.dart#L371) and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The padding you are using is for listviews children, you can use `Padding` widget like this:

```
Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
          child: ListView(),
 )
```